# Should I allow Javascript in the blogging website that i am developing

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xss

I am experimenting on a blogging website like Tumblr, Blogger...[etc]. In a blogging website user should have full control over what they're posting.

So if I allow users to include Javascript code in blog posts, would that make my site vulnerable to XSS attacks ? (which I think it will)

So what would be the best way ;

1. Allow users to include Javascript in HTML
2. Block all the Javascript code.
3. Something else...(which i don't know)

*I am using PHP/MySQL*

Comment: block block block all javascript and unsafe html elements and attributes, did you know that HTML5 supports COR HTTP requests? so that user can connect to evil site and exchange data...

Comment: You shouldn't even have to ask this question.  No javascript!

Comment: i'd say allow it it will be fun to see what creative javascript code people come up with. only worse that can happen is it could lead to someone possibly stealing a session. no major problem there.

Comment: @DevZer0: Cross-Origing requests can be used for DDoS attack! what you say?

Comment: @DevZer0 — So Mallory creates a blog full of spam with JavaScript in it. Alice visit's Mallory's blog, then Mallory's JavaScript steals the session and Mallory uses it to post an entry in Alice's blog that includes JavaScript that redirects people to Mallory's blog. Bob then visit's Alice's blog, get's redirected and then his blog ends up with the redirection script. Then anyone who visit's Alice's or Bob's or Mallory's blog ends up spreading the JavaScript further. That **is** a major problem!

Comment: No one understands a sarcastic comment

Comment: Sarcasm works very poorly in text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's generally a very bad idea to allow Third parties to execute/inject code into your site.  That's just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Most XSS vulnerabilities come from cookies, and/or same-origin requests (e.g. they could POST to the delete account page).

Sites such as tumblr circumvent this by using subdomains.  A request from http://foo.example.org to http://example.org is treated the same as a request from http://example.com (cross-origin).  No cookies will be passed, so there is no XSS vulnerability.

Of course there are still rootkit scripts around, but users take that risk going to any site with an outdated browser.  Make sure to disclaim that somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's a bad Idea, also don't forget that not all your users have some knowledge in informatics, else if Your want a site for developer your can use for example some websites API like jsfiddle http://doc.jsfiddle.net/api/